# Issue with ConvexOptimization over Matrices with Mathematica 12.2

Tags: mathematical-optimization

With Mathematica 12.2, `ConvexOptimization` was introduced, which, as its name suggests, can solve arbitrary convex optimization problems over matrices [[Language Reference]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexOptimization.html). Using `ConvexOptimization` can help me get around reformulating my problem into `SemidefiniteOptimization`, a step that is cumbersome but otherwise works fine.

Hence, to get started, I'm attempting to solve a trial optimization problem with `ConvexOptimization`.

The following code works as intended.

```
A = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {4, 4}]
ConvexOptimization[-Log[Det[A.X.Transpose[A]]], {Tr[X] <= 1, VectorGreaterEqual[{X,  0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 4}]}, {X \[Element] Matrices[{4, 4}, Complexes]}]
```

However, when I replace the objective function `-Log[Det[A.X.Transpose[A]]]` with `-Log[Det[IdentityMatrix[4] + A.X.Transpose[A]]]` to obtain the following optimization problem:

```
A = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {4, 4}]
ConvexOptimization[-Log[Det[IdentityMatrix[4] + A.X.Transpose[A]]], {Tr[X] <= 1, VectorGreaterEqual[{X,  0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 4}]}, {X \[Element] Matrices[{4, 4}, Complexes]}]
```

and evaluate it, Mathematica produces the following error: The argument [...] should not be scalar valued.

I interpret the resulting stack trace on my PC to mean that Mathematica is likely (erroneously) considering the argument to `Det` a scalar. However, I'm stuck with debugging here.

Would anyone know what might be going wrong? Any suggestions for solving the second optimization problem with `ConvexOptimization` will be very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Too long for a comment)

The basic issue is that evaluating `Plus` does automatic threading when given an explicit matrix (for example, `IdentityMatrix[4] + expr`).

One way to work around the threading behavior for this particular case would be something like

```
A = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {4, 4}];

ConvexOptimization[-Log[Det[B + A . X . Transpose[A]]], 
    {Tr[X] <= 1, VectorGreaterEqual[{X, 0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 4}],
     B == IdentityMatrix[4]}, 
    {X \[Element] Matrices[{4, 4}, Complexes], B \[Element] Matrices[{4, 4}]}]
```

The above will work in the currently released versions. In a future release, it will be possible to take the more general approach of using `Inactive[Plus]`, that is

```
ConvexOptimization[
   -Log[Det[Inactive[Plus][IdentityMatrix[4], A . X . Transpose[A]]]], ...}
```

Comment: It's too bad `Inactive[Plus][IdentityMatrix[4], -Log[Det[B + A . X . Transpose[A]]]]` didn't work.

Comment: Right, I think this may be improved.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation; the provided workaround solves the posted problem. I will update this Q&A once this problem is completely resolved by Mathematica.